# AIX Kernel Extension

Tags: gcc, module, kernel, aix

I have searching everywhere but it seemed that it is not possible to compile AIX kernel module using opensource compilers like GCC.   So is purchasing (or getting the trial license) the XLC compiler from IBM really necessary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything that says GCC can't be used?  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-kernelext.html doesn't say anything about a specific compiler, other than that you can't use the compiler to link (`ld` is a system command, though, not part of XLC).

Comment: According to:   

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-gnu.html

You can compile it as 64bit via -maix64 option in gcc.   I compile, no error, and then use the same "ld" command to load the kernel extension.   If it is compiled with xlc, the ld with its other argument passed will load the kernel extension and execute with no error.   But if compile with gcc (and -maix64 option, and generate some warning as well) the ld will compile with additional warning, and load into kernel without errors.   But when executed from a userspace program kernel crashed.